# Changing paragraph tag color by console

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get all the paragraph tags on a page to be white by putting something into the console. I tried something like this:

```
document.p.style.color = 'white';
```

but that did not work. I know changing the body tag works in the console tho

```
document.body.style.background = 'black';
```

Comment: https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-the-different-ways-to-select-dom-elements-in-javascript

Comment: `document.body` is the one and only one `<body>` tag that can exist in valid HTML, so, that's a convenient property of `document` ... like `document.head` for the `<head>` .... however, you can have more than one `<p>` ... so it makes zero sense to have a `document.p` property ... you'll want `document.querySelectorAll('p')` will get you ALL `<p>` in a NodeList, which you'd need to iterate to access the elements themselves, of course - like `document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => p.style.color = 'white');` - or just use CSS

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You would need to select paragraphs individually or select them in bulk to change their properties.

> **Since there is only 1 body `document.body` works**
>
> But there can be multiple paragraphs so

**You either need to select them by their id**

> `document.getElementById("Id");`
>
> **or you could do:**

`document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => p.style.color = 'white');`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for your answer:

HTML:

```
<p id="ANYTHING_YOU_WANT">ANYTHING_YOU_WANT</p>
```

JS:

```
const VARIABLE_NAME = document.getElementById("ANYTHING_YOU_WANT");

VARIABLE_NAME.style.color = "aqua";
```

Give your class and text instead of ***ANYTHING_YOU_WANT*** and your variable name instead of ***VARIABLE_NAME***...

Comment: sorry, I already have an answer, and I am not looking for a variable. Just something to put into the console to change ALL p tags.